# Cpp force write zip using libzip

Tags: c++, zip, libzip

I am using the header `zip.hpp` (can be found here https://markand.bitbucket.io/libzip/index.html or here http://hg.markand.fr/libzip/file) to zip some files.

To remove the raw files afterwards, I use `remove("myfile.txt")`.

Apparently, `zip.hpp` zips the files at the end of runtime, thus it cannot find the file and doesnt create a zip-folder. If I leave out `remove("myfile.txt")`, everything works fine, except for that I have a couple of files flying around that I only want to have in their zipped form.

Do you have any idea on how to force libzip to write the zip-files?
I would expect if I delete the `archive`-instance, it should force the creation, but apparently the `libzip::Archive`-class doesn't have a destructor (at least I can't find one and `delete archive` throws many errors)

My basic code looks like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <zip.h>
#include "lib/zip.hpp"


int main () {

    libzip::Archive archive("output.zip", ZIP_CREATE);
    std::ofstream outfile ("myfile.txt");
    outfile << "Hello World\n";
    outfile.close();

    archive.add(libzip::source::file("myfile.txt"), "myfile2.txt");

    // delete archive; // throws an error...

    // remove("myfile.txt"); 
    // if left out, output.zip gets created otherwise nothing is created


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libzip::Archive` will write its contents when it goes out of scope. So all you need to do is introduce an aditional scope before removing the file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <zip.h>
#include "lib/zip.hpp"

int main () {

    { // Additional scope 
        libzip::Archive archive("output.zip", ZIP_CREATE);
        std::ofstream outfile ("myfile.txt");
        outfile << "Hello World\n";
        outfile.close();
        archive.add(libzip::source::file("myfile.txt"), "myfile2.txt");
    } // Archive is written now.

    remove("myfile.txt"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats brilliant, why didnt I think of scopes?! Thanks a lot!